# How to use DropdownList selected Value to filter data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html-select

I have a dropdown,a TextBox and a Button,DropDdown contains ColumnNames (Name,Cpr),to see filtered data user selects a value from dropDown,enters a string and clicks Button. For doing this i wrote following code,but unable to get DropDown Selected Value,except this problem code working perfectly.plz tell me where im doing mistake.
**Following is my Controller**

```
 public ActionResult Index(string searchType,FormCollection frm)
        {
            List<SelectListItem> obj = new List<SelectListItem>();
            obj.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Agent Name", Value = "Name", Selected = true });
            obj.Add(new SelectListItem {Text = "CPR Number", Value = "Cpr"});
            ViewBag.cmb = obj;


            var agents = from s in db.Agents
                select s;

            if (searchType != null)
            {
                ViewBag.searchString = searchType;
                string cmbColumnSelection = frm["cmb"];

                switch (cmbColumnSelection)
                {
                    case "Name": // Table=Agent,Column=Name

                        agents = agents.Where(s => s.Name.ToString().Contains(searchType));
                        break;
                    default:
                        agents = agents.Where(s => s.Cpr.ToString().Contains(searchType));
                        break;
                }
            }

            return View(agents.ToList());
        }  `
```

**In View:**

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Agent", FormMethod.Get))
    {
        <p>
            @Html.TextBox("searchType", ViewBag.searchString as string)
            Select Filter : @Html.DropDownList("cmb")
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" />
        </p>
   }
```

Comment: Don't use form collection, just declare the parameter of the action: `Index(string searchType, String cmb)`

Comment: Then how can i get DropDownList selected Value here? `string cmbColumnSelection = frm["cmb"];`

Comment: It is in the input! `String cmb` should contain the value you need

Comment: Thanx.Problem solved . `string cmbColumnSelection = cmb;`

Comment: Please note that the model-view-controller tag is for questions about the pattern. There is a specific tag for the ASP.NET-MVC implementation.

Comment: Did i use model-view tag?i don't think so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't mix action input parameters and form collection. You have a good start with `searchType`, stick to the same with `cmb` and drop form collection altogether:

```
public ActionResult Index(string searchType, String cmb)
```

That's it, `cmb` will contain the value posted from drop down. Just use it now:

```
string cmbColumnSelection = cmb;
```

or even

```
switch (cmb)
{...
```