# Filtering data from a dropdown list selection in ASP.NET MVC 5, C# and Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a database which is accessed through Entity Framework where I'm getting my data from. I have two drop down lists that I want to be able to filter my data with based on the users selection. For example, my table in the database is called `Products` and on one dropdown list I want to be able to filter the products by company and for the other dropdown list I want to be able to filter the products by category. Or if a selection is made from both dropdowns, to filter data based on that criteria.

My `Products` table has columns `CompanyID` for the company and `CategoryID` for the category. They are both foreign keys to other tables (as shown below):

1. For `CompanyID` in the `Products` table, the referenced table is `Companies` which has columns `CompanyID` (primary key), and `Brand Name` (which is what is displayed in the dropdown list)
2. For `CategoryID` in the `Products` table, the referenced table is called `ItemCategories` which has columns `CategoryID` (primary key) and `Category` (which is what is displayed in the dropdown list)

Note: I prefer to keep it this way because the companies and item categories can change periodically and I like being able to update the tables rather than the code, but I think they get read as an int and cannot be converted to a string (at least that's what my error messages have said) which is why I think I'm having such a hard time.

I've tried what seems like 500 different variations of everything I could find, but to no avail. The closest I got was I selected an item on one of the dropdown lists and it returned a list with 0 results. Everything else I've tried it gives me error messages or it just doesn't do anything at all when I click filter. What's confusing me is alot of the examples I've seen uses something like this in their code:

```
products = products.Where(x => x.CompanyID == (prodCompany));
```

It won't let me use the == because it

> Cannot be applied to operands of type int? and string

Last bit I'll add before I show my code so far is I have hundreds of products and have to use a paged list for them or else it takes too long to load and freezes up on me. That's been the other tricky part getting the filtering to work is how the paged list has to be incorporated. I have it working perfectly fine, but when it doesn't have a filter, it currently sorts by an OrderBy method by ProductID. I'm not sure if that is effecting my results or not since I want to filter by CompanyID or CategoryID (but hope is that it still sorts the filtered results by the ProductID)??

Final summary: I'm using ASP.NET MVC 5 with Entity Framework and C#, I want to be able to filter data in my products table in the "Index" view based on a selection from a company list dropdown or a category list dropdown (or both) and if no selection is made it displays all the products (with the paged list). Here is my code as it is currently:

My model class `Product`:

```
public partial class Product
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Product()
    {
        this.ProductOrders = new HashSet<ProductOrder>();
    }

    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Display(Name = "Product ID")]
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM-dd-yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    [Display(Name = "Date")]
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> Date_Entered { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Product Code")]
    public string Product_Code { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Company")]
    public Nullable<int> CompanyID { get; set; }
    [AllowHtml]
    [Display(Name = "Category")]
    public Nullable<int> CategoryID { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Amt In Stock")]
    public Nullable<int> Amt_In_Stock { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Qty Available")]
    public Nullable<int> Qty_Available { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Image")]
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }

    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
    public virtual ItemCategory ItemCategory { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<ProductOrder> ProductOrders { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my `ProductsController`:

```
namespace AMS_ITAMSdb.Controllers
{
    public class ProductsController : Controller
    {
        private ItamsEntities db = new ItamsEntities();

        // GET: Products
        public ActionResult Index(string prodCompany, string prodCategory, int? page)
        {
            ViewBag.prodCompany = new SelectList(db.Companies, "CompanyID", "Brand_Name");
            ViewBag.prodCategory = new SelectList(db.ItemCategories, "CategoryID", "Category");

            var prod = from p in db.Products
                       select p;

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(prodCompany))
            {
                //Filter results based on company selected.
                var pageNumber = page ?? 1;
                var pageSize = 15;
                prod = prod.Where(x => x.CompanyID.Equals(prodCompany));
                var product = db.Products.OrderBy(x => x.ProductID).ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize);
                return View(product);
            }
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(prodCategory))
            {
                //Filter results based on company selected.
                var pageNumber = page ?? 1;
                var pageSize = 15;
                prod = prod.Where(x => x.CategoryID.Equals(prodCategory));
                var product = db.Products.OrderBy(x => x.ProductID).ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize);
                return View(product);
            }
            else
            //var product = db.Products.OrderBy(x=>x.ProductID).ToList();
            {
                var pageNumber = page ?? 1;
                var pageSize = 15;
                var product = db.Products.OrderBy(x => x.ProductID).ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize);
                return View(product);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Finally my index view:

```
@using AMS_ITAMSdb.Models;
@using PagedList;
@using PagedList.Mvc;
@model PagedList.IPagedList<Product>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Products</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Products", FormMethod.Get))
{
<p>
    Company: @Html.DropDownList("prodCompany", "All")

    Category: @Html.DropDownList("prodCategory", "All")
    <input type="submit" value="Filter" />
</p>
}

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            Date
        </th>
        <th>
            Product Code
        </th>
        <th>
            Description
        </th>
        <th>
            Amt In Stock
        </th>
        <th>
            Qty Available
        </th>
        <th>
            Image
        </th>
        <th>
            Company
        </th>
        <th>
            Category
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Date_Entered)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Product_Code)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Amt_In_Stock)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Qty_Available)
            </td>
            <td>
                <img src="~/Images/@item.ImageUrl" width="100" height="100" />
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Company.Brand_Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ItemCategory.Category)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.ProductID }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.ProductID }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.ProductID })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
<link href="~/Content/PagedList.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div></div>
(Page @(Model.PageCount < Model.PageNumber ? 0: Model.PageNumber)/@Model.PageCount)

    @Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Index", new { page = page }))
```

Comment: If your companyId is supposed to be an integer value, then why did you declare `prodCompany` as a string? Use the proper date type, then you can compare correctly.

Comment: @mason Based on all the examples I found of filtering data with dropdown lists, they all declared a string there. The dropdown lists I have show text so I thought maybe it needed to be a string since the selection was a text. The CompanyID column in the Products table shows the records from the Companies table from the Brand_Name column. The CompanyID is an int obviously, but the Brand Name is a text data type. I'm not 100% sure how my code is reading that, whether it is reading the text value of the selection or the int value of the ID? So that's why I did that.

Comment: @mason I also saw in all the examples I found where they all used 'if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(stringName))' so if I change the data type, how do I change that statement or declaration if it's an integer? And based on my code provided, if I changed the strings to integers, am I on the right track with my current code? Or am I way off? I'm hoping to get some direction on where to go from where I'm at because I'm totally stuck.

Answer (score 0):

After nearly two weeks of banging my head on the wall trying to figure this out, I finally figured it out from trying something I saw on another question on here at: [dropdown list selected value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39640979/10391548) that I found. My code was really close, it ended up just being a minor tweak which is what I thought would happen smh. Anyways, the fix I found was on my controller where I added .ToString() to my filter which allowed me to use the int in the string and changed the 'Equals' to 'Contains'. A couple other minor changes I made was I added another string (string currentFilter) and I added an if statement. New code I changed in the controller is:

```
    if (prodCompany != null)
            {
                page = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                prodCompany = currentFilter;
            }
            ViewBag.currentFilter = prodCompany;           

            var prod = from p in db.Products
                           select p;

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(prodCompany))
            {
            //Filter results based on company selected.
                var pageNumber = page ?? 1;
                var pageSize = 15;
                prod = prod.Where(p => p.CompanyID.ToString().Contains(prodCompany));
                return View(prod.OrderBy(p => p.ProductID).ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
            }
            //var product = db.Products.OrderBy(x=>x.ProductID).ToList();
            {
                var pageNumber = page ?? 1;
                var pageSize = 15;
                var product = db.Products.OrderBy(p => p.ProductID).ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize);
                return View(product);
            }
        }
```

and on my index view I had to just make one tiny change at the bottom for the paging element:

```
@Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Index", new { page, currentFilter = ViewBag.currentFilter }))
```